# Limits and Summation of Series

Tags: calculus, limits

Find the value of $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\binom{n}{k}}{n^k(k+3)}$$

I am not sure how to progress. I feel as though Squeeze theorem might somehow be used but I can't see to comprehend how.

Can someone please help?

Comment: It definitely converges, since the expression within the limit is less than $\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k} \frac{1}{n^k} = \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n < e$.

Comment: Exactly, but The (k+3) term is throwing me off as to what the solution is.

Comment: A duplicate of [Evalute $ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum^{n}_{k=0}\frac{\binom{n}{k}}{n^k(k+3)} $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1851800/evalute-lim-n-rightarrow-infty-sumn-k-0-frac-binomnknkk3)

Answer (score 5):

Hint:
$$\left(1+\frac{t}{n}\right)^n-1=\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k}\frac{t^k}{n^k}$$

and hence
$$ \int_0^1 t^2\left(\left(1+\frac{t}{n}\right)^n-1\right)dt=\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{(k+3)n^k}$$

Now $(1+\frac{t}{n})^n\leq \exp(t)$, you can use the DCT.

Comment: (+1) Well done. So the limit is $\int_{0}^{1}t^2(e^t-1)\,dt = e-\frac{7}{3}$.

Comment: @Kelenner Can you please expand a little more on the second step? I haven't completely comprehended it.

Comment: Put $f_n(t)  t^2\left(\left(1+\frac{t}{n}\right)^n-1\right)$. Then we have that $f_n(t)\to t^2(\exp(t)-1)=g(t)$. We have also that $0\leq f_n(t)\leq g(t)$ as $(1+\frac{t}{n})^n\leq \exp(t)$. By the Dominated convergence theorem, $\int_0^1f_n(t)dt \to \int_0^1g(t)dt$. It remains to compute $\int_0^1g(t)dt$ (see the comment by Jack D'Aurizio)

Comment: @Kelenner Hey, thanks for the reply.I understood this step. I actually was asking for the step by which you equated the integral and the summation.

Comment: I probably do not understand your question. I have multiplied by $t^2$ and then integrated from $0$ to $1$ each term of the sum.